# To return multiple rows

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please check the code below:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataset);
                return dataset.Tables[0];
            }

        }
    }
```

This function only returns one row.
If I have many rows in my db and need to add it in a combobox, how should I modify my code?

```
string sql = "select country from CarCountry";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (DR.Read())
                    {
                        combobox1.Items.Add(DR[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I use the code above to add items in a combobox.
I would like to write a function to replace it...

Comment: Your function returns one `table` not `row`.

Comment: What do you mean this returns only 1 row? It returns a table. And there is nothing in here to indicate it would return only 1 row.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I mean how I can modify table[0]?
I tired many ways but didn't get what I needed.

Comment: Are you trying to bind the result of a call to this function to a combo box?

Comment: Modify it to do what exactly? What do you need? What did you try?

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your help! appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns one [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), not a [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx). Which is fine, but if you want to get the rows of the `DataTable`, it's a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) on `DataTable`.

Below uses your method to get a `DataTable`, loop through its `DataRows` and adds an item to your `comboBox1`. This item is the `Username` value of each row gotten from the database. (Granted your `SQL` is different, but it's just an example.)

```
public static void Main(string [] args)
{
    PopulateComboBox(); // Will kick off everything.
}

public static void PopulateComboBox()
{
    DataTable table = ExecuteDataTable("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE firstname = @firstname", new SqlParameter("Bob", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(row["Username"].ToString());
    }
}

public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            return dataset.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that is the part I did't get!

Comment: Consider up-voting/accepting helpful answers for others who come across the same problem.

Comment: Yes, no problem, I just did. Thank you.